# Javascript not working in WP7 WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, epub

I am trying to make an ebook (epub) reader on wp7. I am able to successfully read and display the page in `WebBrowser` control and is working fine.

Now I am trying to split the html page into parts to make feel like ebook reading.

To split the page I am using following js:

```
void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      int columnCount = (int)Math.Floor(wb.Height / wb.Width) + 1;
      int columnWidth = columnCount * 100;

      String js = "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
                "d.style.WebkitColumnCount=" + columnCount + ";" +
                "d.style.WebkitColumnWidth='" + columnWidth + "%';";


       wb.InvokeScript("eval", "javascript:(function(){" + js + "})()");


}
```

but it is not working and even it is not showing any error too. The same js is working in android web view for the purpose.

Where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Style properties with names like "WebkitFoo" are particular to WebKit browsers and they'll be ignored by others (except maybe Opera :-)

Comment: so what should I use for wp7?

Comment: Well I'm not sure; I don't know anything about that browser (other than that it's not a WebKit-based browser).

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 multi-column layouts are only available currently as proprietary extensions (Webkit-Column and Moz-Column for Safari/Chrome and Firefox, respectively). Like Opera, Internet Explorer does not currently have a proprietary CSS multi-column layout implementation and thus you will have to create columns the old-fashioned way for the time-being.

The good news is that IE 10 does support it through the actual specification. So the situation will likely change with Windows Phone 8.